# Usar un solo return en la definicion de una funcion

Tags: c, funciones

Estoy usando el libro Aprendiendo C en 21 días en el capitulo 5 nos enseñan el uso de funciones, las variables de retorno y los parametros. En este ejercicio se busca hacer que en la definicion de funcion SOLO se use un 1 return. Usé una variable local para guardar el valor mayor entre a y b pero a la hora de mandar a llamar la función en main creo que algo no sale bien, cuando compila pide los numeros pero en lugar de decir cual es mayor sale 6422292. ¿Qué hice mal? ¿Qué puedo hacer? Gracias.

```
    /* Reescribir el codigo para que sólo se use un return 

     ****CODIGO ORIGINAL***
   
    Demuestra el uso de varios return en una funcion */

    #include<stdio.h>

    int x,y,z;

    //Prototipo de funcion
    int MasLargo_De(int a, int b);

   int main()
   { 
   puts("Ingresa dos valores: \n");

   scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

   z=MasLargo_De(x,y); //se manda a llamar la funcion
   printf("\n El valor mas largo es: %d",z);

  return 0;
  }

  int MasLargo_De(int a, int b) //Se usan 2 return, return a y return b
  {
  if(a>b)
    return a;
  else
    return b;
   }
```

---

//CODIGO NUEVO (REESCRITO)

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int x,y,z;

//Prototipo de funcion
int MasLargo_De(int a, int b);

int main()
{
puts("Ingresa dos valores: \n");
scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

z=MasLargo_De(x,y); //se manda a llamar la funcion
printf("\n El valor mas largo es: %d",z);

    return 0;
} 

//Problema: usar un solo return en la definicion de la funcion

int MasLargo_De(int a, int b)
{   int u;  //variable local

if (a>b)
    a=u;
else
    b=u;

return u;

 }
```

Comment: Esto ... en C, la asignación es `destino = valor`. Lo estás haciendo al revés en tu función `MasLargo_De( )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien te han dicho en un comentario, las igualdades funcionan destino=valor, es decir, lo que escribas a la derecha de la igualdad se guardara en la izquierda.
Tu estás haciendo `a=u` y `b=u`, estas guardando en `a` y `b` el valor de `u`, como `u` no tiene ningún valor asignado anteriormente te devuelve 6422292 que es lo que se denomina "valor basura"(un numero residual que ha quedado en memoria).
Lo que necesitas es guardar el valor de `a` o `b` en `u`, es decir, `u=a` y `u=b`

Un consejo, las variables siempre deben de tener nombres descriptivos, en lugar de `a, b, u`.... usa, por ejemplo, `valor1, valor2, valorMayor`, te será mucho más fácil entender el código, sobre todo cuando lo abras meses después.

Tu código quedaría así (en base al segundo ejemplo que has escrito)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int x,y,z;

//Prototipo de funcion
int MasLargo_De(int a, int b);

int main()
{
  puts("Ingresa  dos valores separados con un espacio \n");
  scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);



  z=MasLargo_De(x,y); //se manda a llamar la funcion
 printf("\n El valor mas largo es: %d",z);

   return 0;
} 

//Problema: usar un solo return en la definicion de la funcion

int MasLargo_De(int a, int b)
{   
  int u;  //variable local

  if (a>b)
    u=a;
  else
    u=b;

  return u;


}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedó muy claro con lo del valor basura de u.